# How to prevent sveltekit from treating my components as a route?

Tags: sveltekit

As far as I understand, to create a route in sveltekit, you need to follow these rules:

- Create files within `src/routes` folder
- Name them according to the desired path

If I need a route like `https://example.com/users/:userId` I need to create a `[user-id].svelte` file inside `src/routes/users/` directory. It's clear.

But.

What if I want all of my page-related components to live next to the page?

I would do something like this

```
- src/
  - routes/
    - users/
      - components/
        - avatar.svelte
      [user-id].svelte
```

Now, I am able to use this component as a route (e.g. `https://example.com/users/components/avatar`).

How to prevent this? I don't want my components to be treated as a route

Comment: The accepted answer is a fine solution, your other option is to have a components folder in the lib directory. When you import into a page you only need to: "import Comp from '$lib/components... etc".

Comment: Hey, the currently selected correct answer is no longer correct. I posted an up-to-date answer. Please, consider marking it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: The following answer contains outdated information from before the 1.0 release of SvelteKit. As of [v1.0.0-next-406](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/releases/tag/%40sveltejs%2Fkit%401.0.0-next.40), an overhauled filesystem router was released changing things considerably. For this question, in particular, components are no longer treated as routes by default—routes are now [especially marked components](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page) so we don't get unexpected routes.*

Files and directories prefixed with `_` are ignored by SvelteKit, so you could have your component at `src/routes/users/_components/avatar.svelte`.

Comment: Ah just found that sveltekit calls it private modules. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#private-modules

Comment: I think this is no longer the case in the current version of SvelteKit

Answer (score 0):

## October 2023 update

The current version of SvelteKit is [1.25.2](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/releases/tag/%40sveltejs%2Fkit%401.25.2) and any folder that doesn't have a file prefixed with `+` (`+page.svelte`, `+server.svelte`, etc.) is not treated as a route.

So you can name your components folder however you want as long as it doesn't contain routing files.

Example:

```
src/routes/
├ users/
│ ├ foo/ <-- works, no routing files
│ │ └ Foo.svelte
│ ├ bar/ <-- doesn't work, contains +page.svelte
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ └ +page.svelte
└ +page.svelte
```